# Ajax: How to call a controller function to update the <option> tags with new data?

Tags: php, ajax

I am Struck at ajax part wherein i am trying to call a php controller function to update the drop down list,

Scenario 2 Drop down list, 
1) Country ,
2) Cities

Based on the selection of country from dropdown of Country i need to enable cities list at Cities dropdown and simultaneously trying to display the hotels available in that country and in that selected city.

Request to know like How to call the controller function inside ajax?

Comment: This is a type of programing what called tree system. That is not hard, How can send the country code (parent) to your server side language and select all of the cities that there country is that code (parent). YOU SOULED HAVE A COUNTRY FIELD IN YOUR CITY DATABASE

Comment: too broad and no codes to start with

Comment: you mentioned controller.. are u using codeigniter?

Comment: Which framework are you using, different frameworks have different way to handle AJAX?

Comment: You can call the ajax and return select html and replace the innerhtml of the div where you want to show the cities dropdown with the ajax response. 

I think you want the same thing like this. 

http://dev.tasolglobal.com/osclass/sep_cpviewer-p22

Comment: @Smruti Singh, No not codeigniter? Just followed with the MVC of WordPress

Comment: @user3752043 ok, i posted an answer based on codeigniter, may be that can give you some hint

Comment: @Veerendra Yes i need a similar way to implement, whether the link you shared is on mvc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOnt know if you are using codeigniter or not, but i do it in codeigniter this way

FIrst let me show the td_country and td_city table

```
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|    country_id     |       country_title             |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|       1           |           India                 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|       2           |         Sri Lanka               |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
```

and td_city

```
|----------------------------------------|
| city_id |   city_title |   country_id  |
|----------------------------------------|
|    1    |   Delhi      |       1       |
|----------------------------------------|
|    2    |   Columbo    |       2       |
|----------------------------------------|
```

This will be your view page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_city(country)
    {
        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>ajax/get_city",{'country':country},
        function(data) 
        {
            $('option', '#city').remove();
            content ="<option value=''>Select City</option>";
            $('#city').append(content);
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                    content ="<option value="+data[i].city_id+">"+data[i].city_title+"</option>";
                    $('#city').append(content);
            }
        }, "json");
    }

</script>


<select id="country" name="country" onchange="get_city(this.value)">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
<?php
foreach($country as $c)
 {?>
<option value="<?php echo $c['country_id'];?>"><?php echo $c['country_title'];?></option>
<?php
 }?>
</select>
<select id="city" name="city">
<option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

Now in the ajax.php controller here's the script

```
<?php
class ajax extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

public function get_city()
    {
        $country_id=$_POST['country'];
        $city=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM td_city WHERE td_city.country_id = '$country_id'")->result_array();     
        $data['city'] = json_encode($city);
        echo $data['city'];
    }
}
?>
```

Hence the suggestion

```
[EDIT: as asked by OP in the comments]
```

Suppose I have a controller called `common.php`

and it contains two methods(functions) name `func_first()` and `func_second()`.

If we need to call func_second() form func_first() then in case of codeigniter we do it this way

```
<?php
class common extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

function func_first()
   {
     $var = $this->func_second();
   }

function func_second()
   {
     $ret = 1;
     return $ret;
   }
}
?>
```